# playing an intro video for a website on iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, video

I have been doing some research into what is possible, as far as I can tell

### Autoplay

Possible to autostart videos on early versions of IOS http://www.codeblog.co/getting-autoplay-working-on-ios/ although this no longer works on current version (exact version it stopped working I don't know). Behaviour seems to be the same on both the iPad and iPhone?

### Playing video in page

On the iPhone videos always pop out to player, its not possible to play in page.

However is possible to play videos in page on the iPad - have tried out the videos on here and they do play inline.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

### Playing as intro video

May be able to do an enter now button for the site with below code to trigger

```
<input type="button" value="Play" onClick="document.myMovie.play()">
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10

Could then on iPad make this take the full screen in page in website and use js to detect when the video finishes. Am thinking on iPhone may not be possible to detect when video finishes?

**Can anyone clarify what is possible?**

As much as I know intro video aren't too popular, this is a requirement for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic play is not possible on iOS as fas sa I'm aware. They removed support on purpose to stop people from doing it.

Any playback now requires the user to actually specify for the video to play, so providing a button to play it should be fine?

Comment: It seems it can be triggered by a custom button, I am interested if it has been done before and whether it is possible to tell when the video finishes in order to transition into the site. Am thinking it may be possible on an iPad and not an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you keep your video in the bundle and play it with MPMovieePlayer.Then you won't need to autoplay the video,the video will be played autometically itself.As I do the same thing.

Comment: is this for apps that are downloaded through the app store? I am looking have this functionality for a website, although I haven't seen it done before am thinking it may be possible on the ipad and not the iphone?

Comment: Thats possible for both iPhone and iPad bro.......You use the same SDK.....Well If you are getting video from your website it will then take time in the beginning to play at the video as you either need to do live streaming or play it with webview in which you need to press the button....Well I suggest you to get that video and keep it in your application and the performance of the app would be good as well.If the video is same, I mean you are not going to change the intro video every time through your website.The choice is yours....Enjoy